# TypeScript - How do you infer an interface generic argument

Tags: typescript, generics

I am looking for a solution to have the interface infer a generic argument by what is given at code time instead of having to specify it (because in my use case it won't be possible to specify it).

Here's what I wish to make

```js
interface Field<T> {
    value: T;
    onChange: (value: T) => void;
}

interface Options {
    fields: {
        [key: string]: Field; // Requires a type argument...
    };
}

const options: Options = {
    fields: {
        name: {
            value: "John",
            onChange: (value) => { /* ... */ }, // type of "value" should be string
        },
        age: {
            value: 2,
            onChange: (value) => { /* ... */ }, // type of "value" should be number
        },
        other: {
            value: { sex: "male", money: 1337 },
            onChange: (value) => { /* ... */ }, // type of "value" should be { sex: string, money: number }
        },
    }
};
```

In this example (which doesn't work), `Options.fields` will be a collection of `Field`s which their value type is not yet known until it is written. However, because `Field` has a `<T>` argument, it must be specified in `Options.fields` in order to pass the typings. But that type could be anything. I want the type of `onChange` to be inferred from whatever the type of `value` is.

This seems to work for functions

```js
function fn<T>(param: T) {
    return param;
}
const test = fn(2); // type of test: number (2)
```

In this example, I was able to use a function that requires a type argument without specifying it, because it inferred it from the parameter I passed in. I would like this kind of behavior for the interface too.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that. You either need to give *specific* types for each key, e.g., `name: Field<string>, age: Field<number>` or if you want a collection of any amount and any type of them, you have to somehow combine all types. Either using `[key: string]: Field<any>` or restricting this to "only" a union of all possible types `[key: string]: Field<string | number | { sex: string, money: number }>` yet neither will let you know the specific generic. If you do `options.fields.[anyKey]` you'd get `any` or the union type as a generic type, not each generic that you have stored there.